# Simple summation problem regarding origin of summand:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

If
$$\frac{1}{\sigma_\widehat{e}^2}=\sum_i\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}\tag{1}$$

Pick any one of the $\sigma_j$ and multiply both sides of $(1)$ by $\sigma_j^2$

$$\implies\frac{\sigma_j^2}{\sigma_\widehat e^2}=\color{red}{\fbox{$\sum_i\frac{\sigma_j^2}{\sigma_i^2}=\color{blue}{1}+\sum_{i\ne j}\frac{\sigma_j^2}{\sigma_i^2}$}}\tag{2}$$

I'm not sure why the equality holds for equation $(2)$, though I believe I understand the origin of the $\color{blue}{1}$ in equation $(2)$

The $\color{blue}{1}$ is present because $$\color{red}{{\sum_i\frac{\sigma_j^2}{\sigma_i^2}=\underbrace{\sum_{\color{#180}{i=j}}\frac{\sigma_j^2}{\sigma_i^2}}_{\color{blue}{=1}}+\sum_{i\ne j}\frac{\sigma_j^2}{\sigma_i^2}}}$$ but this does not explain the second term on the right hand side of $(2)$.

Does $\sigma_j$ depend on $i$? I thought that it does not; but the notation $$\sum_{i\ne j}\frac{\sigma_j^2}{\sigma_i^2}$$ is confusing me somewhat as it says $i\ne j$ underneath the sum.

Comment: Why _not_ keep it in the summand?

Comment: @Slade Because $\sigma_j$ does not depend on $i$ unless I am mistaken. I also thought that terms that do not depend on the summation index should be factored out as constants.

Comment: We _can_ factor it out.  That doesn't mean we have to.  This is really a question of personal taste.

Comment: Whether $\sigma_j^2$ remains inside or outside the summand does not matter as long as it is kept a constant while doing the summing.

Comment: I love anonymous downvotes

Comment: From what's written, no, $\sigma_j$ does not appear to depend on $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\displaystyle\sum_{i\ne j}$ is infelicitous because it is at best ambiguous.  Sometimes it means $\displaystyle\sum_{i,j\,:\,i\ne j}$  and sometimes it means $\displaystyle\sum_{i\,:\,i\ne j}$.  The latter is the proper meaning in this instance.

For example, suppose $1\le i\le 3$ and $j=1$.  Then we have
$$
{\sum_i\frac{\sigma_j^2}{\sigma_i^2}= \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2} + \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_2^2} + \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_3^2} = 1 + \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_2^2} + \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_3^2} = \underbrace{\sum_{i\,:\,i=1} \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_i^2}}_{=1}+\sum_{i\,:\,i\ne 1} \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_i^2}}.
$$

Comment: good point.  Still in context I thought it was clear.

Comment: @Michael Perfect answer; as ever, thank you very much. I'm glad you mentioned the part about ambiguity as that was what I _think_ was confusing me.

Comment: @Michael Since, you answered this question so well I was wondering if you could take a look at another question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582971/tricky-proof-that-the-weighted-average-is-a-better-estimate-than-the-un-weighted) that is similar to this one.

Comment: @Michael I don't know if you received the last comment or not but please could you take a look at this similar [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582971/tricky-proof-that-the-weighted-average-is-a-better-estimate-than-the-un-weighted)? As a user with the same first name as yours has posted a great answer but it is too difficult for me to understand. Your answers appeal to my intuition very well, will you please help me by giving a more simple answer to it? Regards, Blaze.

Answer (score 1):

Think it out slowly.

$\frac 1 {e^2} = \sum_i \frac 1 {a_i^2}$

So $\frac {a_j^2}{e^2} = a_j^2 \sum_i \frac 1 {a_i^2} = \sum_i \frac {a_j^2} {a_i^2}$

Now $\frac {a_j^2}{a_i^2} = \{1 \text { if } j = i \mid \frac {a_j^2}{a_i^2}\text{ if }j \ne i \}$

So $\frac {a_j^2}{e^2} =  \sum_i [\frac {a_j^2} {a_i^2}\mid 1] = $

$\sum_{i < j}\frac {a_j^2} {a_i^2} + \sum_{i=j} 1 + \sum_{i > j}\frac {a_j^2} {a_i^2} = $

$1 + \sum_{i < j}\frac {a_j^2} {a_i^2} +  \sum_{i > j}\frac {a_j^2} {a_i^2}=$

$1 + \sum_{i \ne j}\frac {a_j^2} {a_i^2}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, nice idea separating out the equality into inequalities.

Comment: Well, the idea that seemed to be confusing was the idea that rho_i was "influencing" by forcing the other rhos to stop being j.  I wanted to impress that all that's really happening is that *one* rho_j cancels to 1 but the other stay.  I wanted to show it just happened when rho_j's "turn was up".

Comment: Yes that's it; by `rho_i`/`rho_j` i presume you mean $\sigma_i$/$\sigma_j$ right? Thanks.

Comment: sigma.  lower case sigma.